# What did i do wrong in this JavaScript code

Tags: javascript

I am learning javascript nowadays and i am trying to make a word scramble game via youtube video. When i hit check it always says not correct how can i fix this problem ? What did i do wrong ? (This is my first entry if i do something wrong or deficent please let me know + sorry for my bad english :) )

```js
const wordText = document.querySelector(".word"),
  hintText = document.querySelector(".hint span"),
  inputField = document.querySelector(".input"),
  refreshBtn = document.querySelector(".refresh-word"),
  checkBtn = document.querySelector(".check-word");

// Words/Kelimeler
const words = [
  {
    word: "addition",
    hint: "The process of adding numbers",
  },
  {
    word: "meeting",
    hint: "Event in which people come together",
  },
  {
    word: "number",
    hint: "Math symbol used for counting",
  },
  {
    word: "exchange",
    hint: "The act of trading",
  },
  {
    word: "canvas",
    hint: "Piece of fabric for oil painting",
  },
  {
    word: "garden",
    hint: "Space for planting flower and plant",
  },
  {
    word: "position",
    hint: "Location of someone or something",
  },
  {
    word: "feather",
    hint: "Hair like outer covering of bird",
  },
  {
    word: "comfort",
    hint: "A pleasant feeling of relaxation",
  },
  {
    word: "tongue",
    hint: "The muscular organ of mouth",
  },
  {
    word: "expansion",
    hint: "The process of increase or grow",
  },
  {
    word: "country",
    hint: "A politically identified region",
  },
  {
    word: "group",
    hint: "A number of objects or persons",
  },
  {
    word: "taste",
    hint: "Ability of tongue to detect flavour",
  },
  {
    word: "store",
    hint: "Large shop where goods are traded",
  },
  {
    word: "field",
    hint: "Area of land for farming activities",
  },
  {
    word: "friend",
    hint: "Person other than a family member",
  },
  {
    word: "pocket",
    hint: "A bag for carrying small items",
  },
  {
    word: "needle",
    hint: "A thin and sharp metal pin",
  },
  {
    word: "expert",
    hint: "Person with extensive knowledge",
  },
  {
    word: "statement",
    hint: "A declaration of something",
  },
  {
    word: "second",
    hint: "One-sixtieth of a minute",
  },
  {
    word: "library",
    hint: "Place containing collection of books",
  },
];

let correctWord;

const initGame = () => {
  let randomObj = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)]; //kelimelerden rastgele obje alma /getting random object from words
  let wordArray = randomObj.word.split(""); //Splitting each letter of random word / her kelimeyi rastgele harflere böler
  for (let i = wordArray.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1)); //rastgele sayı alma /geting random num
    let temp = wordArray[i];
    wordArray[i] = wordArray[j];
    wordArray[j] = temp;
  }

  wordText.innerText = wordArray.join(""); //ayırdığımız kelimelerin boşluklarını neyle bağlıyacağımızı seçiyoruz/passing shuffled word as word text
  hintText.innerText = randomObj.hint;
  correctWord = randomObj.word.toLowerCase;
  console.log(randomObj);
};

const checkWord = () => {
  let userWord = inputField.value.toLocaleLowerCase();
  console.log(userWord);
  if (userWord !== correctWord)
return alert(`Oops! ${userWord} is not correct word`);
  alert(`Congrats! ${userWord.toUpperCase()} is correct`);
  if (!userWord) return alert(`Please enter word`);
};

refreshBtn.addEventListener("click", initGame);
checkBtn.addEventListener("click", checkWord);

initGame();
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;500;600&display=swap");
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: #2c3333;
}

.container {
  width: 450px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 7px;
}

.container h2 {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: 18px 25px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.container .content {
  margin: 25px 20px 35px;
}

.content .word {
  font-size: 33px;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 25px;
  margin-right: -25px;
}

.content .details {
  margin: 25px 0 20px;
}
.details p {
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.details p b {
  font-weight: 500;
}

.content input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0 16px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.content .buttons {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 20px;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.buttons button {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 15px 0;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 17px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: calc(100% / 2- 8px);
}

.buttons .check-word {
  background: #a0d995;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
}

.buttons .refresh-word {
  background: #a5c9ca;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Word Scramble Game</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="js/script.js" defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <h2>Word Scramble Game</h2>
      <div class="content">
        <p class="word"></p>
        <div class="details">
          <p class="hint">Hint:<span></span></p>
          <p class="time">
            Time Left:<span><b>30</b>s</span>
          </p>
        </div>
        <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="Enter a valid word" />
        <div class="buttons">
          <button class="refresh-word">Refresh Word</button>
          <button class="check-word">Check Word</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello, you can check [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  This is a good opportunity for you to start familiarizing yourself with [using a debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/328193).  When you step through the code in a debugger, which operation first produces an unexpected result?  What were the values used in that operation?  What was the result?  What result was expected?  Why?  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`toLowerCase` is a function, not a property, so you need to add parenthesis.

```
correctWord = randomObj.word.toLowerCase();
```

```js
const wordText = document.querySelector(".word"),
  hintText = document.querySelector(".hint span"),
  inputField = document.querySelector(".input"),
  refreshBtn = document.querySelector(".refresh-word"),
  checkBtn = document.querySelector(".check-word");

// Words/Kelimeler
const words = [
  {
    word: "addition",
    hint: "The process of adding numbers",
  },
  {
    word: "meeting",
    hint: "Event in which people come together",
  },
  {
    word: "number",
    hint: "Math symbol used for counting",
  },
  {
    word: "exchange",
    hint: "The act of trading",
  },
  {
    word: "canvas",
    hint: "Piece of fabric for oil painting",
  },
  {
    word: "garden",
    hint: "Space for planting flower and plant",
  },
  {
    word: "position",
    hint: "Location of someone or something",
  },
  {
    word: "feather",
    hint: "Hair like outer covering of bird",
  },
  {
    word: "comfort",
    hint: "A pleasant feeling of relaxation",
  },
  {
    word: "tongue",
    hint: "The muscular organ of mouth",
  },
  {
    word: "expansion",
    hint: "The process of increase or grow",
  },
  {
    word: "country",
    hint: "A politically identified region",
  },
  {
    word: "group",
    hint: "A number of objects or persons",
  },
  {
    word: "taste",
    hint: "Ability of tongue to detect flavour",
  },
  {
    word: "store",
    hint: "Large shop where goods are traded",
  },
  {
    word: "field",
    hint: "Area of land for farming activities",
  },
  {
    word: "friend",
    hint: "Person other than a family member",
  },
  {
    word: "pocket",
    hint: "A bag for carrying small items",
  },
  {
    word: "needle",
    hint: "A thin and sharp metal pin",
  },
  {
    word: "expert",
    hint: "Person with extensive knowledge",
  },
  {
    word: "statement",
    hint: "A declaration of something",
  },
  {
    word: "second",
    hint: "One-sixtieth of a minute",
  },
  {
    word: "library",
    hint: "Place containing collection of books",
  },
];

let correctWord;

const initGame = () => {
  let randomObj = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)]; //kelimelerden rastgele obje alma /getting random object from words
  let wordArray = randomObj.word.split(""); //Splitting each letter of random word / her kelimeyi rastgele harflere böler
  for (let i = wordArray.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1)); //rastgele sayı alma /geting random num
    let temp = wordArray[i];
    wordArray[i] = wordArray[j];
    wordArray[j] = temp;
  }

  wordText.innerText = wordArray.join(""); //ayırdığımız kelimelerin boşluklarını neyle bağlıyacağımızı seçiyoruz/passing shuffled word as word text
  hintText.innerText = randomObj.hint;
  correctWord = randomObj.word.toLowerCase();
};

const checkWord = () => {
  let userWord = inputField.value.toLocaleLowerCase();
  if (userWord !== correctWord)
return alert(`Oops! ${userWord} is not correct word`);
  alert(`Congrats! ${userWord.toUpperCase()} is correct`);
  if (!userWord) return alert(`Please enter word`);
};

refreshBtn.addEventListener("click", initGame);
checkBtn.addEventListener("click", checkWord);

initGame();
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;500;600&display=swap");
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: #2c3333;
}

.container {
  width: 450px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 7px;
}

.container h2 {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: 18px 25px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.container .content {
  margin: 25px 20px 35px;
}

.content .word {
  font-size: 33px;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 25px;
  margin-right: -25px;
}

.content .details {
  margin: 25px 0 20px;
}
.details p {
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.details p b {
  font-weight: 500;
}

.content input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0 16px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.content .buttons {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 20px;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.buttons button {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 15px 0;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 17px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: calc(100% / 2- 8px);
}

.buttons .check-word {
  background: #a0d995;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
}

.buttons .refresh-word {
  background: #a5c9ca;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Word Scramble Game</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="js/script.js" defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <h2>Word Scramble Game</h2>
      <div class="content">
        <p class="word"></p>
        <div class="details">
          <p class="hint">Hint:<span></span></p>
          <p class="time">
            Time Left:<span><b>30</b>s</span>
          </p>
        </div>
        <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="Enter a valid word" />
        <div class="buttons">
          <button class="refresh-word">Refresh Word</button>
          <button class="check-word">Check Word</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Then you should add a comment and vote to close as: "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo. While similar questions may be on-topic here, **this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers.**"_

Answer (score 0):

You are missing parentheses `see my comment in code on line 116`

```js
const wordText = document.querySelector(".word"),
  hintText = document.querySelector(".hint span"),
  inputField = document.querySelector(".input"),
  refreshBtn = document.querySelector(".refresh-word"),
  checkBtn = document.querySelector(".check-word");

// Words/Kelimeler
const words = [{
    word: "addition",
    hint: "The process of adding numbers",
  },
  {
    word: "meeting",
    hint: "Event in which people come together",
  },
  {
    word: "number",
    hint: "Math symbol used for counting",
  },
  {
    word: "exchange",
    hint: "The act of trading",
  },
  {
    word: "canvas",
    hint: "Piece of fabric for oil painting",
  },
  {
    word: "garden",
    hint: "Space for planting flower and plant",
  },
  {
    word: "position",
    hint: "Location of someone or something",
  },
  {
    word: "feather",
    hint: "Hair like outer covering of bird",
  },
  {
    word: "comfort",
    hint: "A pleasant feeling of relaxation",
  },
  {
    word: "tongue",
    hint: "The muscular organ of mouth",
  },
  {
    word: "expansion",
    hint: "The process of increase or grow",
  },
  {
    word: "country",
    hint: "A politically identified region",
  },
  {
    word: "group",
    hint: "A number of objects or persons",
  },
  {
    word: "taste",
    hint: "Ability of tongue to detect flavour",
  },
  {
    word: "store",
    hint: "Large shop where goods are traded",
  },
  {
    word: "field",
    hint: "Area of land for farming activities",
  },
  {
    word: "friend",
    hint: "Person other than a family member",
  },
  {
    word: "pocket",
    hint: "A bag for carrying small items",
  },
  {
    word: "needle",
    hint: "A thin and sharp metal pin",
  },
  {
    word: "expert",
    hint: "Person with extensive knowledge",
  },
  {
    word: "statement",
    hint: "A declaration of something",
  },
  {
    word: "second",
    hint: "One-sixtieth of a minute",
  },
  {
    word: "library",
    hint: "Place containing collection of books",
  },
];

let correctWord;

const initGame = () => {
  let randomObj = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)]; //kelimelerden rastgele obje alma /getting random object from words
  let wordArray = randomObj.word.split(""); //Splitting each letter of random word / her kelimeyi rastgele harflere böler
  for (let i = wordArray.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1)); //rastgele sayı alma /geting random num
    let temp = wordArray[i];
    wordArray[i] = wordArray[j];
    wordArray[j] = temp;
  }

  wordText.innerText = wordArray.join(""); //ayırdığımız kelimelerin boşluklarını neyle bağlıyacağımızı seçiyoruz/passing shuffled word as word text
  hintText.innerText = randomObj.hint;
  correctWord = randomObj.word.toLowerCase(); // You are missing parentheses here
  console.log(randomObj);
};

const checkWord = () => {
  let userWord = inputField.value.toLocaleLowerCase();
  console.log({userWord, correctWord});
  if (userWord !== correctWord)
    return alert(`Oops! ${userWord} is not correct word`);
  alert(`Congrats! ${userWord.toUpperCase()} is correct`);
  if (!userWord) return alert(`Please enter word`);
};

refreshBtn.addEventListener("click", initGame);
checkBtn.addEventListener("click", checkWord);

initGame();
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;500;600&display=swap");
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: #2c3333;
}

.container {
  width: 450px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 7px;
}

.container h2 {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: 18px 25px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.container .content {
  margin: 25px 20px 35px;
}

.content .word {
  font-size: 33px;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 25px;
  margin-right: -25px;
}

.content .details {
  margin: 25px 0 20px;
}

.details p {
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.details p b {
  font-weight: 500;
}

.content input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0 16px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.content .buttons {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 20px;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.buttons button {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 15px 0;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 17px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: calc(100% / 2- 8px);
}

.buttons .check-word {
  background: #a0d995;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
}

.buttons .refresh-word {
  background: #a5c9ca;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h2>Word Scramble Game</h2>
  <div class="content">
    <p class="word"></p>
    <div class="details">
      <p class="hint">Hint:<span></span></p>
      <p class="time">
        Time Left:<span><b>30</b>s</span>
      </p>
    </div>
    <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="Enter a valid word" />
    <div class="buttons">
      <button class="refresh-word">Refresh Word</button>
      <button class="check-word">Check Word</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of JSFiddling, I logged when it set the correct answer and found that: You are setting the `correctAnswer` Variable to a function (specifically `toLocaleLowercase`. What you want is to call that function and set `correctAnswer` to the value: (ln 117)
`correctWord = randomObj.word.toLocaleLowerCase()`

Comment: No problem! This is also one of my first answers to a stackoverflow post.